# How to open linkedin profile using firstname and lastname in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, linkedin-api

i want to open linkedin profile.how to pass firstname and lastname of user in application to get linkedin profile of that user can be shown..please help me for that.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the People Search API (https://developer.linkedin.com/api/people-search) to generate a list of matches. Then have the member select the correct person.

Note: your member needs to sign into the application using OAuth. You cannot have a generic role account who searches for people.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe linkedin offers a direct link to a profile based solely of first and last name. Some folks have the same name as other people.

This might be a good place to start learning about their API: https://developer.linkedin.com/apis